# Executing multiple queries in codeigniter that cannot be executed one by one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an "event" table. For simplicity, you can imagine that it should be like a **hierarchical category**. It uses the **nested set model** (Thanks to Mark Hillyer for his post at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

My code:

```
$query = 
"LOCK TABLE event WRITE;
SELECT @ParentRight := parent.rgt, @Level := parent.level FROM event AS parent WHERE parent.id = '{$data['parent_id']}';

UPDATE event SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @ParentRight;
UPDATE event SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @ParentRight;

INSERT INTO event(lft, rgt, level) VALUES(@ParentRight, @ParentRight + 1, @Level);
UNLOCK TABLES;";

mysqli_multi_query($this->db->conn_id, $query);

$data['id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
return $this->db->update('event', $data);
```

And after that I'm going to update the last inserted object with `$this->db->update('event', $data)`

`$data` is an array that user has filled.

---

Problem 1:

I couldn't execute **$query** with **$this->db->query($query);**;

Solution 1 that didn't work:

I. Use **mysqli** db engine.

II. `mysqli_multi_query($this->db->conn_id, $query);` While I thought it works, it is giving the following error:

`Commands out of sync; you can’t run this command now.`

---

Problem 2:

`$this->db->insert_id()` doesn't work (returns 0)

Problem 3:

`$this->db->update('event', $data);` errors:
`Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

---

How can I correct this code to work? I'd be even happy to find a solution for the first problem.

Comment: You could have an array of single queries and execute them in a loop

Comment: No, as you can see in this case executing as separate queries doesn't work because it cannot recall `@myRight` and `@Level` vars from past queries' results

Comment: Are variables not preserved until you disconnect?

Comment: What I know is just that the vars are not accessible after the query that declares them, is left.

Comment: Wow, that's odd behaviour, because I thought the semicolon would denote the end of the statement anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "odd behavior". At end of each mysql command there IS a semicolon. I think that don't understand your speech :-/ As I've updated my question, recently I got that even using `mysqli_multi_query()` doesn't work!

Comment: @smhnaji What is the error message in problem 1?

Comment: What I mean is that your SQL string is split up into several SQL statements with semicolons.  For example LOCK TABLE event WRITE; is a single SQL statement, the semicolon (;) symbol at the end marks the end of the statement.  While there is only a single string of SQL, that string contains multiple statements.

Comment: @zrvan Added the error message to Problem#1. Thank you for your notice :)

Comment: @GordonM Sorry for misunderstanding your previous comment. Yes, I am using multiple statements at the same query because I couldn't execute them one by one. Because the second command hold a variable that should be used later.

Comment: What about using `SELECT FOR UPDATE`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe use transactions?

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: Don't forgot to check all query executed or not by checking transaction status $this->db->trans_status() https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695559/5803974

Answer (score 4):

Why not just write a stored procedure that does all the SQL you listed above taking the variables in your queries as parameters. Then just call the stored procedure as a single SQL statement;

```
$sql = "CALL some_sp($param1, $param2...etc)";
```

Comment: Codeigniter not allows to run a query with multiple statement in a single $this->db->query($sql); function call. we cannot use the point you mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

**You Can Simply Use the following:**

```
 print_r($this->db->query("YOUR query NO 1") ? 'Success Q1' : $this->db->error());
 print_r($this->db->query("YOUR query NO 2") ? 'Success Q2' : $this->db->error());
 print_r($this->db->query("YOUR query NO 3") ? 'Success Q3' : $this->db->error());
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Wo_Products` WHERE `boost_plan`=1 AND `tamatar`=1 AND`active`=1 ORDER BY rand()  LIMIT 3");

$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Wo_Products` WHERE `boost_plan`=2 AND `tamatar`=1 AND`active`=1 ORDER BY rand()  LIMIT 3");

$query3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `Wo_Products` WHERE `boost_plan` NOT IN (0,1) AND `tamatar`=1 AND`active`=1 ORDER BY rand()  LIMIT 6");

    $result1 = $query1->result();
    $result2 = $query2->result();
    $result3 = $query3->result();
    return array_merge($result1, $result2, $result3);
```