# Codeigniter Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter transactions

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

This works fine , the problem I have is that inside the `trans_start` and `trans_complete` I'm calling other functions and those functions deals with database so they contains inserts and update and some deletes ... ex:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
 $this->utils->insert_function($data);
 $this->utils->update_function2($test);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Now if those functions are executed and some errors occur CodeIgniter won't do a rollback.

What is the best way to deal with such issue?

The only solution, I have in mind, is to return an error from those functions and inside those function add (`trans_stat` and `trans_complete`) And if it returns an error test an do `$this->db->trans_rollback`

ex:

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
     $result = $this->utils->insert_function($data);
     if($result === false){
       $this->db->trans_rollback();
     }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**Update 1:**

As requested a sample of the external function i'm calling :

```
   // insert_function contains

    $rec = array(
        'numero' => $numero,
        'transaction_id' => $id,
        'debit' => $product_taxes['amount_without_taxes'],
        'date' => $data['date_transaction'],
    );
    $this->addExerciceAccountingRecords($rec);

  and addExerciceAccountingRecords contains

   function addExerciceAccountingRecords($records) {
    $this->db->insert('transactions_exercices', $records);
    }
```

Comment: What Storage Engine are you using for your MySQL tables?
Also, how do you know that the roll back failed?

Comment: @MarcAudet INNODB , I know because When there is a rollback is not applied on tables modified during the function call inside the trans_start

Comment: Can you post the code to utils->insert_function and utils->insert_function2 ? I have a notion of what the issue might be...

Comment: One more question: is utils in the libraries folder?

Comment: yes , it contains helpers functions

Comment: Give me a few minutes to type up an answer for you...

Comment: I'd suggest up-voting any answers you found useful

Comment: Example roytuts.com/codeigniter-transaction-example/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> > Using `transactions` means support databases to insert data safely. So in Codeigniter we write every **database related functions in the *Model* not in Controller.**. And in your second code(which is not working)you have pointed model on there.(**`utils`**). So simple I'm sure this will not work. Because its not a insert data with model and Controller parallel. Transaction should be coded in the Model(**I will write in Model in my answer**).

---

**Load this stuffs as well**

1. Database Library
2. Model Class
3. URL helper
4. Session

---

**Assumptions**

In your code you have used `$data` and `$test` as array. So i assume there is two array for inserting and updating data.

---

**Your data sets**

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$id = 007;
$test = array(
   'title' => $title,
   'name' => $name,
   'date' => $date
);
```

**Your Code**

```
$this->db->trans_start(); # Starting Transaction
$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE); # See Note 01. If you wish can remove as well 

$this->db->insert('table_name', $data); # Inserting data

# Updating data
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('table_name', $test); 

$this->db->trans_complete(); # Completing transaction

/*Optional*/

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    # Something went wrong.
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return FALSE;
} 
else {
    # Everything is Perfect. 
    # Committing data to the database.
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return TRUE;
}
```

---

**Notes**

1. By default Codeigniter runs all transactions in Strict Mode.  When
   **strict mode is *enabled*, if you are running multiple groups of transactions, if one group fails all groups will be rolled back. If
   strict mode is *disabled***,  each group is **treated
   independently**, **meaning a failure of one group will not affect
   any others**.

Comment: trans_complete() already does a status check and rollback/commit

Comment: @AL-zami Why you remove those ?? **Don't Conflict the content**

Comment: @spartan those few lin i edited was for manual transaction.see the documentation for your self https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: @AL-zami bro its to manage errors. Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#managing-errors

Comment: if trans_complete() commits automatically, in the "ELSE"  case it will commit again...don't you think it is a problem !

Comment: there are two options as follows - 1) remove else condition or 2) remove $this->db->trans_complete(), please check manual & update your answer.@Spartan

Comment: **Make sure to use $this->db->trans_begin() when running manual transactions, NOT $this->db->trans_start().**

Comment: @Shihas Why? When examining the code, `trans_start()` actually calls `trans_begin()` with same parameters and there is no additional check in place either. Perhaps readability.

Comment: in my case i want to make order at that time one order have **multiple order item in separate table** so when i make order i want to transaction.

step-1: i insert order in order table.
step-2: based on **order inserted id** use in **order item table** it multiple in one order. when order item inserted at that time i check order time availability if order item quantity not available i want roll back all transaction  but `$this->db->trans_status()` getting true how can do it.

**i Try a lot but not work when availability fail i just `$this->db->trans_rollback();` but it can not roll back**

Comment: Hello @AbdullaNilam, is it really possible to run $this->db->trans_complete(); and then run $this->db->trans_rollback(); ?

Comment: @ValterEkholm yes. `trans_complete` only write your data in DB. if failed Rollback will remove partial saved on DB

Answer (score 8):

What I tried was more of a trick, but it worked for me.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
  $rst1=  $this->utils->insert_function($data);
  $rst2 =  $this->utils->update_function2($test);
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE || !isset($rst1) || !isset($rst2)){
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
}else{
   $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem has to do with how CodeIgniter is handling objects.

If you go to the CI documentation under the section "Creating Libraries" at:
 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html
and look at the section related to:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
```

In your main controller, you have loaded/instantiated the database class either using auto load or explicitly loading the class.

You then go ahead and open the transaction, and then, you access your database 
functions through your utils library.

However, once you use `$this-db` in your library, you are actually accessing another copy of the database instance, NOT the one that is associated with your transaction.

To access the same instance, you need to use the get_instance() function.

I  think that should fix your problem.  Your original coding style to separate function
into various modules is excellent.  You simply need to understand this additional detail.

Please try and confirm that the roll back works as you expect.

The guts of the code consists of the following controller:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->User_profile_m->create_new_user_profile();
$this->User_profile_m->create_new_user();
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

and a simple model `user_profile_m` to deal with data persistence:

```
function create_new_user()
{
    $data['user_name_usr'] = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $data['create_date_usr'] = NULL;

    $this->db->insert('user_usr', $data);  
}

function create_new_user_profile()
{
    $data['user_name_pro'] = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $data['user_description_pro'] = $this->input->post('user_description');
    $data['create_date_pro'] = NULL;

    $this->db->insert('user_profile_pro', $data);  
}
```

Essentially, the demonstration tries to do two inserts (one in each of two tables).
If one insert fails, the other is rolled back.

I built this in CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and I can make the application files available through GitHub or zip them up and send them to you.

Comment: Sorry maybe i gave a bad example , the problem occurs even if the insert function is in the same model and i call it by ($this->insertFunction...)

Comment: Hi Tarek, did you try get_instance() ? I am a bit curious about this; you are not doing anything out of the ordinary.  Let me think about this over a cup of coffee, please check in later today.

Comment: @Marc Audet: when update operation return 0 (affected row) then transaction is rollback or not? Thanks.

Comment: @secretim Good question.  You really should be checking `$this->db->trans_status()` instead of `$this->db->affected_rows()`, since the affected row result can vary depending exactly where you place the statement (inside or outside the transaction block).

Answer (score 4):

Try this procedure. It really work for me :)

```
$this->db->trans_start();
   $this->utils->insert_function($data);
   $this->utils->update_function2($test);
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
}else{
   $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Comment: trans_complete() already does a status check and rollback/commit

Answer (score 3):

Note: Make sure to use `$this->db->trans_begin()` when running manual transactions, NOT `$this->db->trans_start()`.

```
$this -> db -> trans_begin(); 
$this -> utils -> insert_function ( $data );
$this -> utils -> update_function2 ( $test ); 
$this -> db -> trans_complete ();
```

Certify in case use MySql, use in InnoDb Format

Comment: Why is this upvoted? In both versions (2 & 3), it's `start/complete` and `begin/rollback/commit`.

Answer (score 0):

For single insert or update record you can use affected_rows function

```
$this->db->insert('table_name', xss_clean($data));


//Check if there is a record affected
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
              {
                  return true;
              }
              else
              { 
                  // if not succeeded
                  // check your last query 
                  die($this->db->last_query());
              }
```