# Database transaction not working in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am calling multiple models in controllers and all models do database query.
i did something like this

```
public function InsertSale()
    {
            $this->db->trans_start(TRUE);
            // all logic part and models calling which do insert/update/delete

            $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Above code is not working even if something fails after some queries they dont rollback.

Comment: Why would you even have DB transaction in anything that you want to calls "a controller"?!

Comment: Related https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/101648/

Comment: Remove `TRUE` try using `$this->db->trans_start();` By default its true.I am using transaction like yours and working fine.So it should work for you too.

Comment: @tereško for changes that involve several models, for instace.

Comment: @Sebastianb what do you mean by "models"?

Comment: @tereško the M in MVC, the models used in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Ah, well .. what CodeIgnoter has are not "models". They are just table abstractions. Besides, "model" is not a class but a layer. Basically, you end up with all the business logic being dumped in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Having `true` in `$this->db->trans_start(true);` will put the transaction in to test mode which means that, regardless of what happens, the query will be rolled back.

If you wanted to see if the query would work you would use:

```
$this->db->trans_status();
```

Which will return either `true`/`false` depending on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

So that you have to follow like this

```
$this->db->trans_start(); # Starting Transaction
$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE); 

$this->db->insert('table_name', $someDataArray); # Inserting data

# Updating data
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('table_name', $someDataArray); 

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

This is work fine. [Check this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695559/4595675)