# What happens to inserted records when a model function returns before it reaches to rollback or complete?

Tags: php, transactions, commit, codeigniter-3, rollback

I am trying to test transaction management in codeigniter. Below method is a function in a model class. If ***update_user_company_id*** method returns false, wrapper method ***save_user_and_company*** also returns. In this case, because the method returns before it reaches to

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

call, changes made by ***save_company*** and ***delete_company_requests*** methods are rolled back. This is what I want.

But what I want to learn is that instead of calling

```
$this->db->rollback();
```

I directly return from method. 
Is this approach safe? 
Is there a possibility that I may encounter a lock or some other problem in the future?

```
function save_user_and_company($user, $company_request) {

    $result[STATU] = ERROR;
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $company = $this->companies_dao->save_company($company_request->company_name, $user->id);
    if (!$company) {
        $result[MESSAGE] = COMPANY_SAVE_ERROR;
        return $result;
    }

    $company_request_result = $this->company_requests_model->delete_company_requests($company_request->id);
    if (!$company_request_result) {
        $result[MESSAGE] = COMPANY_REQUEST_DELETE_ERROR;
        return $result;
    }

    $user_update = $this->users_dao->update_user_company_id($user->id, $company->id);
    if (!$user_update) {
        $result[MESSAGE] = USER_UPDATE_ERROR;
        return $result;
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    $result[STATU] = SUCCESS;
    $result[MESSAGE] = SUCCESSFUL;
    return $result;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple it get save. Seems no rollback in  your code. Once it reach first return it will terminate all the below code and returns  the output.

Comment: read this https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224826/codeigniter-transactions/34695559#34695559

Comment: No, I have tested it again. It rollbacks the changes of save_company. save_company just adds a record into db. When I return just after it, I see no record in db. So I conclude it automatically rollbacks because it doesn't reach $this->db->trans_complete(); If I didn't use $this->db->trans_start(); in the beginning of the method I would expect it to behave just like you suggested but this is different. In this case I say that I am responsible for the transaction management and neither do I complete nor rollback, I just return. I wonder this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this....

Following code returns `TRUE` if transaction completes successfully.Otherwise it `rollback` your transaction and returns `FALSE`.Hope it will help you a lot..

```
function save_user_and_company($user, $company_request) {

    $this->db->trans_begin(); //Begins your transaction

    //Performs the transaction operations
    $company = $this->companies_dao->save_company($company_request->company_name, $user->id);
    $company_request_result = $this->company_requests_model->delete_company_requests($company_request->id);
    $user_update = $this->users_dao->update_user_company_id($user->id, $company->id);

    //Check whether transaction fails

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
      $this->db->trans_rollback();
      $status = FALSE;
    }
   else
    {
      $this->db->trans_commit();
      $status = TRUE;
    }

    return $status;
}
```