# how to use transactions in codeigniter for commit and rollback based on data change?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I want to learn how I could use **MYSQL TRANSACTIONS**.

I have use case where I have two tables. Let say Table1 and Table2. Now I insert some data in Table1 and the `insert id` I get from that table I want to insert it into table 2.

If values are successfully inserted in Table1, and during the insertion of Table2 values if any error occurs I want to delete the values from Table1 as well, as the query for my Table2 was not successful.

I just want to understand how this could be done using Codeigniter.
How to COMMIT or ROLLBACK as per need.

Please help me with some sample code to understand.

**Update**

I also referred the Codeigniter UserGuide. But I did not understood the concept of `Running Transactions manually` What does this mean ? As mentioned above I want to do something like trigger which is automatic, I mean if my query fail I want it to ROLLBACK whatever it did, using Codeigniter.

Code:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$data = $this->Product_m->array_from_post(array('name','description'));
$this->Product_m->save($data,$id);
$pid = $this->db->insert_id();

$num_of_license = $_POST['license'];

$this->Product_m->create_product($pid,$num_of_license);
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else
    {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
```

Now in this case I tried doing this:

This statement `$this->Product_m->create_product($pid,$num_of_license);` inserts data based on the previous save() method, Now suppose some error occurs during create_product() method. Then I want to rollback. I want to delete the record that save() method did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Transactions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224826/codeigniter-transactions)

Comment: it's not a duplicate he just asked for a reference of transaction done in codeigniter

Comment: @dhruvjadia that question i have already referred  but it is specifically regarding his code, I just wanted to understand how i could use it in different ways, Also i have mentioned I want to "Learn"

Answer (score 18):

Use the following steps.

1.Begin your transaction using `$this->db->trans_begin();`.

2.Performs queries.

3.Check Transaction status using `$this->db->trans_status()`.

4.If `status` is true `commit` transaction  using `$this->db->trans_commit();`.

5.If `status` is false `rollback` transaction using `$this->db->trans_rollback();`.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Transaction](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html)

Comment: could you explain me with this use case scenario where i insert a record and based on that record insert another record, but while inserting my second record in second table if error occurs i want to delete even the first record that i inserted

Comment: Will  $this->db->trans_rollback(); delete all records   under this transaction?

Comment: yea ..all the queries performed after `trans_begin` will be roll backed. Did you try anything according to above steps.

Comment: could please check the updated question I have tried using this but when My second query fails it does not roll back the save method's query! How do i do it

Comment: Yes i did try, But the rollback is not working suppose i have a db error in my second method, so i want to roll back, i want to delete what save() method inserted

Comment: rather than calling model for saving data.use queries at controller.

Comment: OKay let me try