# Using CodeIgniter transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

Is there any difference between using

`$this->db->trans_start();`

and using

`$this->db->query('START TRANSACTION');`?

Actually, I wish to apply this question to other programming languages, such as **C#** with `BeginTransaction()`.

When do you explicitly write out that you want to begin a transaction in a query and when do you just invoke a built-in method from the framework or whatever language you are using?

Comment: I'd use the framework method, when possible. It may come with specific error handling, events, logging etc. that you'd miss out on with a raw query. In CI, you'd be missing out on the `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` query it runs first: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/9e17059bf8d277058d1de23390e388b5fa0cc26a/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php#L294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** Is there any difference between using
**Answer**: No. Both do the same sort of job.

---

**Explanation**

If You need to get know about CI Transaction Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695559/4595675) on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224826/codeigniter-transactions).

But By only using `$this->db->query()` you can't archive transaction part comletly.

> **I Recommend this personally** [Read this Documentaion](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions)

---

**Question:**  When do you explicitly write out that you want to begin a transaction in a query and when do you just invoke a built-in method from the framework or whatever language you are using?
**Answer:** (based on PHP/CI)It's based on what kind a system you do.

**Explanation**

For example, if you have simple product add and its have many child tables. (assume 1 master and 4 child tables). so once one of the child ***table throws an error, data remain at the upper-level table***. So to prevent that we should use Transaction on here.

Assume `Child Table 2` occurred an error and this what happens (**for Inserted Data**).

```
| Table Name    | Normal Insert     if          |
                    /update     | Transaction   |
|    ------     |     ------    |    ------     |
| Master Table  | Remain        | Roalbacked    |   
| Child Table 1 | Remain        | Roalbacked    |
| Child Table 2 | Error         | Roalbacked    |
| Child Table 3 | Empty         | Nothing to do |
| Child Table 4 | Empty         | Nothing to do |
```

---

**Useful Links**

1. [Transactions - codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)
2. [My Answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224826/codeigniter-transactions/34695559#34695559)
3. [php-mysql transaction - mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-transaction/)

Comment: well explained. This should be added to CI documentation.