# transaction can't rollback in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, codeigniter-3

I am working on transaction , and in mentioned code I faced some problem. I didn't commit the transaction , but it inserted data into my database.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->insert('tblorder',$data);
$orderid=$this->db->insert_id();
foreach ($orderItemList as $orderItemList) {
    $orderitem = array('orderid' =>$orderid ,'productid' =>$orderItemList->productid ,'amount' =>$orderItemList->amount);
    $this->db->insert('tblorderitem',$orderitem);
}
$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() == 1) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return "true";
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return "false";
}
```

I rolled back transaction , and again all data was inserted in my database. What must be the problem? I can't get it.

Answer (score 8):

**Do not use `$this->db->trans_complete();`**

as per [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually)

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER UPDATED!

I have to tell you the default of codeigniter´s config is automatically commit all transactions.

If for any reason you want to disable this function you have to use this line:

```
$this->db->trans_off();
```

before of

```
$this->db->begin();
```

Said that, so when you use

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

you will need to commit or rollback, like this:

```
$result = $this->db->trans_complete();

if($result === true){
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}else{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Finally what you want is:

```
$this->db->trans_off();

$this->db->query("insert this...");
$this->db->query("insert that...");

$result = $this->db->trans_complete();

if($result === true){
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}else{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Comment: i want rollback transaction than what will do?

Comment: You are wrong about the use of `trans_off()`. Once that is run none of the other `trans_` method will execute. Well... technically they execute but once they see that `trans_off()` has been called they immediately return FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

As I know for CI version 3.0.1 the only thing that you should worry about is where to put `$this->db->trans_start();` and `$this->db->trans_complete();`

So for situations like:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
//any code goes here
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Transaction will be rolled back if something goes wrong, or will be committed on call to `$this->db->trans_complete();`

Because if you look under the hood of **trans_start** method it contains **trans_begin**. And **trans_complete** method contains check for **trans_status** and accordingly calls to **trans_commit** or **trans_rollback** methods.

Same applies for nested transactions:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
//any code goes here
$this->db->trans_start();
//any code goes here
$this->db->trans_complete();
//any code goes here
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

By default Codeigniter runs all transactions in Strict Mode so on last **trans_complete** all will be committed, or if anything fails all rollbacks.

Answer (score 2):

*Why* do you want to `ROLLBACK`?  Is it because of something *other* than a false `trans_status`?  If so, call `trans_rollback` *before* calling `trans_complete` or `trans_commit`.

It sounds like this would be optimal for your situation (apologies for incorrect syntax):

```
trans_start
...
if ( some non-db problem )  trans_rollback
trans_complete
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this. ***If you want to Learn more about the Transaction [Check My answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695559/4595675). That helps you to get a clear idea about Transactions.***

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->insert('tblorder',$data);
$orderid=$this->db->insert_id();

$orderitem = array();

foreach ($orderItemList as $orderItemList) 
{
    $orderitem[] = array('orderid' =>$orderid ,'productid' =>$orderItemList->productid ,'amount' =>$orderItemList->amount);
}

$this->db->insert_batch('tblorderitem', $orderitem); 

$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) 
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return FALSE;
} 
else 
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written is pretty much the same as way automatic transactions  are written - only not as well. My advice? Don't try to outsmart CodeIgniter, use the "automatic" mode for transactions. Then rollbacks, if required, will be taken care of for you.

I've redone your code using automatic transactions mode. I also collect the data from `$orderItemList` so it can be inserted using a batch instead of calling `db->insert` repetitively in a loop.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert('tblorder', $data);
$orderid = $this->db->insert_id();
foreach($orderItemList as $orderItem)
{
    $orderedItems[] = [
      'orderid' => $orderid,
      'productid' => $orderItem->productid,
      'amount' => $orderItem->amount
    ];
}
if(isset($orderedItems))
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('tblorderitem', $orderedItems);
}
$this->db->trans_complete();
$this->db->trans_status();
```