# how to use result sets from stored procedure in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stored-procedures

how to perform multiple queries in single stored procedure and then use result we get by all queries in our model. I get **Query error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now error** when try to use the result of the stored procedure. Here is my code :

**In Model: **

```
    /* convert post array data to string */
    $pr = "'" .implode("', '", $data) . "'";
    $pr2 = "'" .implode("', '", $data2) . "'";
    $pr5 = "'" .implode("', '", $data4) . "'";

    /* call stored procedure */
    $this->db->query('CALL addCustomerSalesData("'.$pr.'", "'.$pr2.'", "'.$pr5.'", @CustSalesID, @CustSalesProID)');

    /* get the stored procedure returned output */
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT @CustSalesID AS cust_sales_id, @CustSalesProID AS cust_sales_pro_id');
    $row = $query->row_array();

    /* this will release memory which is used by stored procedure and make it free for another process */
    $query->next_result();
    $query->free_result();

    /* return inserted id*/
    return $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running two querys in one. So mysql consume more memory to hold them

```
$this->db->query('CALL addCustomerSalesData("'.$pr.'", "'.$pr2.'", "'.$pr5.'", @CustSalesID, @CustSalesProID)');

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT @CustSalesID AS cust_sales_id, @CustSalesProID AS cust_sales_pro_id');
```

**What can you do**

1. Store First and execute second
2. or `$query->free_result();` in between two query to free up those

Comment: hey thanks @DeadManAlive bt i want to run all queries simultaneously, can you please tell me how can i use $query->free_result();

Comment: as you say **i want to run all queries simultaneously**, save first` $result = $this->db->query('CALL ....` and run second one. Read [Codeigniter Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224826/codeigniter-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use more than one select in stored procedure, to avoid **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now error**  what you need to do is:

**find this file :
System/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php**

**in this file find function : function _execute($sql) { }**

change this to:

```
protected function _execute($sql)
{
    // Free result from previous query
    @mysqli_free_result($this->result_id);

    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);

    // get a result code of query (), can be used for test is the query ok
    $retval = @mysqli_multi_query($this->conn_id, $sql);

    // get a first resultset
    $firstResult = @mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id);

    // free other resultsets
    while (@mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id)) {
        $result = @mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id);
        @mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    // test is the error occur or not
    if (!$firstResult && !@mysqli_errno($this->conn_id)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $firstResult;
}
```